# @nuxtjs/composition-api reactive array watch not woking

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

```js
const progress = <any>reactive([])
const onUploadProgress = (index: number) => ({ loaded, total }: { loaded: number, total: number }) => {
    console.log('onUploadProgress', progress)
    progress[index] = Math.round((loaded / total) * 100)
}

// not working
const progress_sum = computed(() => {
    console.log('progress_sum', progress)
    return progress.reduce((s: number, x: number) => s += x, 0)
})

// not working
watch(() => progress, (values) => {
    console.log('ww', values)
}, { deep: true })

// not working
watch(() => [...progress], (values) => {
    console.log('ww', values)
}, { deep: true })
```